# What is the difference between providing that and provided that?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, differences, word-usage

Please tell me about this question and give me an example for each one.
Is it conjunction or not?
Thanks

Comment: Provided that is in a sense something that is already given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally use "provided that" (in fact, I've always thought "providing that" was just wrong, but I've just checked Merriam Webster, and, apparently, both "provided" and "providing" are equally acceptable. So it's your call. :-)

Comment: I agree entirely. Whilst preferring 'provided' I accept 'providing' is possible.

Comment: So the MW reference makes this general reference.